# Auto fill gmail register with webbrower control error

Tags: c#, automation, gmail, browser

I used webbrower to set automatic values for gmail register form, when i fill capcha and submit , the server give message "Sorry, we cannot serve your request for a new account at this moment. ". I register manual it's success. Could you explain me why ?

here is my code .

```
HtmlElement element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("LastName");
        if (element != null) {
            string lastName = "LastName";
            element.InnerText = lastName; 
          }
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("lastname-placeholder");
        if (element != null) { element.InnerText = ""; }

        // First Name
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("firstname-placeholder");
        if (element != null)
        {
            element.InnerText = "";
        }
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("FirstName");
        if (element != null) {
            string firstName = "firstName";
            element.InnerText = firstName;

            element.InvokeMember("onblur");
        }

        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("GmailAddress");
        if (element != null)
        {
            string account="abcxxx";// 

            element.InnerText = account;

            element.InvokeMember("onblur");
            element.InvokeMember("onChange");

            element.InvokeMember("onFocus");
        }
        // Password
        string password = "abc123xxx";
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Passwd");
        if (element != null) {
            element.InnerText = password;
            emailCreated.Password = password;

            element.InvokeMember("onFocus");
            element.InvokeMember("onblur"); element.InvokeMember("onChange");
        }

        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PasswdAgain");
        if (element != null) { element.InnerText = password; element.InvokeMember("onFocus"); element.InvokeMember("onblur"); element.InvokeMember("onChange"); }

        // Day
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("birthday-placeholder");
        if (element != null)
        {
            element.InnerText = "";
        }
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("BirthDay");
        if (element != null) { element.InnerText = "14"; element.InvokeMember("onblur"); }

        // Month
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("BirthMonth");
        if (element != null)
        {
            element.SetAttribute("SelectedIndex", "2"); element.InvokeMember("onblur");

        }
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("HiddenBirthMonth");
        if (element != null)
        {
            element.InnerText = "02";
        }
        //Year
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("birthYear-placeholder");
        if (element != null)
        {
            element.InnerText = "";
        }
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("BirthYear");
        if (element != null) { element.InnerText = "1986"; element.InvokeMember("onblur"); }


        // Gender
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Gender");
        if (element != null) { element.SetAttribute("SelectedIndex", "1"); element.InvokeMember("onblur"); }
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("HiddenGender");
        if (element != null) { element.InnerText = "FEMALE"; element.SetAttribute("value", "FEMALE"); element.InvokeMember("onblur"); }


        //RecoveryPhoneNumber
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("RecoveryPhoneNumber");
        element.InnerText = txtMobileRecover.Text;


        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("RecoveryEmailAddress");
        element.InnerText="mailabcxxx@gmail.com"

        //TermsOfService
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("TermsOfService");
        if (element != null) { element.SetAttribute("checked", "true"); element.InvokeMember("onblur"); }
        //HomepageSet
        element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("HomepageSet");
        if (element != null) { element.SetAttribute("checked", ""); element.InvokeMember("onblur"); }
        // images
```

Comment: manually enter the captcha him at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recaptcha is js so if you created few accounts from that ip you have to wait some time ...

Even if you clear cookies including flash cookie your ip is saved.

As far as i know if you manage to see that msg your code is correct and you passed all client side form validations.  That msg is from server, try testing it on some other computer.